# How to split Dataframe column into two parts and replace column with splitted value

Tags: python

How can I split a dataframe column into two parts such that the value in dataframe column is later replaced by the splitted value.
For example, I have a dataframe like :

```
col1       col2
"abc"      "A, BC"
"def"      "AX, Z"
"pqr"      "P, R"
"xyz"      "X, YZ"
```

I want to extract values before , and replace that cell with the extracted value.
So, the output should look like :

```
col1   col2
abc    A
def    AX
pqr    P
xyz    X
```

I am trying to do it as :

```
df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
```

But it gives me error. Please suggest how can I get the desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you can you the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) methods of `pandas`, that will use vectorized functions.
It will also be faster that `apply`.

```
df.col2 = df.col2.str.split(', ').str[0]

>>> df
Out[]:
  col1 col2
0  abc    A
1  def   AX
2  pqr    P
3  xyz    X
```

To use this on `Series` containing string, you should call the `str` attribute before any function.
See the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) for more details.

In the above solution, note the `.str.split(', ')` that replace `split`.
And `.str[0]` that allow to slice the result of the split, whereas just using `.str.split(', ')[0]` would get index 0 of the `Series`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me a little bit more. What i need to do is : 
I have a dictionary with the state name mapping like 
states_names_mapping = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
        'AZ': 'Arizona',
        'CA': 'California',
}

And a dataframe column Place like 
Place
California, USA
Beverly Hills, CA
California
CA
NY, USA
USA

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me a little bit more. What i need to do is : 
I have a dict for state name mapping like 
state_map={
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
}
And a dataframe column Place like 
California, USA
Beverly Hills, CA
California
CA
NY, USA
USA
I need to replace this column values with the state names.

Comment: if(df['Place'])!=''
    if df['Place'].str.split(', ').str[0] in state_map.values():
        df['New'] = df['Place'].str.split(', ',).str[0]
    elif df['Place'].str.split(', ').str[1] in state_map.values():
        df['New'] = df['Place'].str.split(', ',).str[1]
    elif df['Place'].str.split(', ').str[0] in state_map.keys():
        for i in state_map:
            df['New'] = state_map[i]
            break
    elif df['Place'].str.split(', ').str[1] in state_map.keys():
        for i in state_map:
            df['New'] = states_names_mapping[i]
            break

Comment: But it gives me error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: I'll have a look, but you should add this to the body of your question to preserve to code format.

Comment: Thank you, It will be great help if you could help me to sort this asap. If you had any problem in understanding, I can repost it as a new question or If i can send it to you some other way.

Comment: https://github.com/Rachel-Z/Problems/issues/1

I posted it here also in a proper format.

Comment: @Ritika, found your new post. You can close this question by approving the answer that you judge solved the problem described above.

Comment: Thank you Fabien. Really appreciate your help !!