# Python: Check if dataframe cell value exists in Dictionary. If exists replace dataframe value with dictionary key

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a csv file(or dataframe) like below :

```
Text    Location    State
A   Florida, USA    Florida
B   NY              New York
C       
D   abc
```

And a dictionary with key value pair as :

```
stat_map = {
        'FL': 'Florida',
        'NY': 'NewYork',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
}
```

How may I delete row 3rd and 4th i.e. row with Text C & D so that my dataframe contains only those rows for which i have value in dictionary. 
The final output should look like :

```
Text    Location    State
    A   Florida, USA    Florida
    B   NY              New York
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi (again) @Ritika, you should always add some sample data to illustrate your question (like data you [mentioned previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748369/how-to-split-dataframe-column-into-two-parts-and-replace-column-with-splitted-va/46749556?noredirect=1#comment80464195_46749556)).

Comment: Hi Fabien, I am new to Python and stack overflow, sorry for these problems. I updated my post. 
What I am actually doing is that i am downloading some tweets in a json file, extracting text and location from the json file into a dataframe. Now I further need to aggregate all tweets location wise and perform sentiment analysis and topic modelling location wise. The dataframe location column has values like 'CA', 'USA', ' XYZ, CA', 'CA, USA', 'California'. Some are also blank and some are random values. 
Could you please help me with the sentiment analysis and topic modelling state wise.

Comment: The code i posted above is to replace different formats of location to one particular location format for all tweets. But this gives error. Further i need to do sentiment analysis and topic modelling on those tweets.

Comment: You just replaced this question with a new one after it had been answered. Moreover it is duplicate of the [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784707/python-deleting-rows-from-dataframe-for-which-value-does-not-exist-in-dictionar) you opened. I don't understand why you did that, it is very bad practice, the answer has no context anymore and won't serve to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`pandas.Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), which replaces a value by that provided in a `mapper`, here `states_map`.

I will reuse data from you [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748369/how-to-split-dataframe-column-into-two-parts-and-replace-column-with-splitted-va/46749556?noredirect=1#comment80464195_46749556) for illustration

```
import pandas as pd

states_map = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'CA': 'California',  # Enrich the dict for the current example
        'NY': 'New York'     # Same as above
}

>>> df
Out[]:
               State
0    California, USA
1  Beverly Hills, CA
2         California
3                 CA
4            NY, USA
5                USA
```

Using the discussed method with `map` will give

```
states = df['State'].str.split(', ').str[0]

>>> states
Out[]:
0       California
1    Beverly Hills
2       California
3               CA
4               NY
5              USA
Name: State, dtype: object

>>> states.map(states_map)
Out[]:
0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3    California
4      New York
5           NaN
Name: State, dtype: object
```

---

But this is not optimal, as you loose information from row 1 with the `split` and from rows 0 and 2 with the `map`.

I think it can be done better like this:

#### Get all terms from `split` using `expand=True`

```
df_parts = df.State.str.split(', ', expand=True)

>>> df_parts
Out[]:
               0     1
0     California   USA
1  Beverly Hills    CA
2     California  None
3             CA  None
4             NY   USA
5            USA  None
```

#### Get places where the state is correct

```
mask = df_parts.isin(states_map.values())

>>> df_parts[mask]
Out[]:
            0    1
0  California  NaN
1         NaN  NaN
2  California  NaN
3         NaN  NaN
4         NaN  NaN
5         NaN  NaN
```

Using `~` (bitwise NOT) gives us the inverse of the mask.

```
df_unknown = df_parts[~mask]

>>> df_unknown
Out[]:
               0     1
0            NaN   USA
1  Beverly Hills    CA
2            NaN  None
3             CA  None
4             NY   USA
5            USA  None
```

#### Use `map` where state is not known

```
>>> df_unknown.apply(lambda col: col.map(states_map))
Out[]:
            0           1
0         NaN         NaN
1         NaN  California
2         NaN         NaN
3  California         NaN
4    New York         NaN
5         NaN         NaN
```

And set these values in masked `df_parts`

df_parts[~mask] = df_unknown.apply(lambda col: col.map(states_map))

```
>>> df_parts
Out[]:
            0           1
0  California         NaN
1         NaN  California
2  California         NaN
3  California         NaN
4    New York         NaN
5         NaN         NaN
```

#### Reunify values

```
>>> df_parts[0].fillna(df_parts[1])  # Fill blanks in col 1 with values in col 2
Out[]:
0    California
1    California
2    California
3    California
4      New York
5           NaN
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Replace curated values in original dataframe

```
df['State_new'] = df_parts[0].fillna(df_parts[1])

>>> df
Out[]:
               State   State_new
0    California, USA  California
1  Beverly Hills, CA  California
2         California  California
3                 CA  California
4            NY, USA    New York
5                USA         NaN
```

It may not be a perfect approach, but hope it will help.

Comment: Hey Fabien, Thanks for your reply dear. But 
mask = df_parts.isin(states_map.values())

Comment: I manually removed errors and it worked. But how can I use strip or any other function in above code so that it works fine.

Comment: The state column values have spaces as i extracted them from a json file and saved in dataframe. So wherever spaces are there, the logic shared by you does not work, If there are no spaces, it works perfectly. Could you please advise how can i remove spaces. Tried using strip function while storing values in State as 
df['Location'] = list(map(lambda t:t['user']['location'].strip(), data))
but get error that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Hey Fabien, it worked. Really appreciate your help. Thank you so so much.
I got the dataframe now with the text and state column. Would you mind helping me further that how can I do sentiment analysis and topic modelling state wise now. I dont know how to structure the loop  further now to do these state wise.

Comment: @Ritika, you're welcome, glad it worked. You should try a new question if you still need it.

Comment: Hi Fabien, Need one more help please related to this issue. As I stored the vales in State column of dataframe from a json file, I have a long list of  some state values are very random like 'XYZ' or blank which does not even exist. How should I remove such values further from my dataframe. I am updating this post for this problem where I am stuck now so that you could understand the issue and possibly help me one more time

Comment: @Ritika I suggest you address this issue in a new question, with a sample of your df, an your desired output as an example. Then post the link here in comment so I will see it for sure. I will have a look.